# Jquery Moving Boxes multiple use in HTML

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie of Jquery. I downloaded a Moving Boxes code from http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/
It works fine in my HTML file. But my question is **How to use this multiple times in one HTML page?** I copied the HTML code, and change the #slider to .slider in CSS, but it doesn't work as same as the first one. Can anybody know how to fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after I added the comment above, I looked at the Moving Boxes code... it's not written as a plugin so it would involve a lot of changes to make it work properly for multiple sliders. Have you looked at any other sliders? Maybe check out [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) by the same author.

---

Actually, I had some time so I converted the Moving Boxes code into a plugin. I posted the basic directions in [my blog](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/06/moving-boxes-updated.html). [Here is a link](http://www.myotherdrive.com/dyn/file/973.304414.21062010.98364.6a64fi/MovingBoxes.zip) to get a zipped file with an updated demo (zipped file; you need to go to that link to download, I'm not sure why you can't right click and save)